# Ruby - Variables that are defined only once per function call

Tags: c++, ruby, variables, recursion, static

To be more specific I want to find the way in ruby to create "static" vars like in C++. This vars are definied only once per function call. Even if function is recursive.

Now I use global vars for that but it's not good and Causes confusion in a code.
Bellow I paste codes in C++ and Ruby.

```
def my_function
  my_var = 0
  if my_var < 10
    my_var += 1
    my_function
  else
    puts my_var
  end
end
```

In Ruby we have infinite loop because my_var will never be 10

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void my_method(){
  static int my_var = 0;
  if(my_var < 10){
    my_var += 1;
    return my_method();
  } else{
    cout << my_var;
  }

int main(){
  my_method();
}
```

In C++ program will print 10.

So guys, do you know if something like this exists in Ruby? And I don't want to use global vars. I really don't like them.

Regards and thanks
Simon

Comment: Use an instance variable.

Comment: Workaround: define the method as `def my_function(my_var = 0)` and pass `my_var` when recursively calling the method.